# Callback @escaping function objective-c from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement the callback of a Swift function in Objective-C, but it does not show me the following error, "No visible @interface for 'AccessControl' declares the selector 'evaluateWithCompletion:'" which can be seen in the image in more detail.

[image]

I'm using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.3

The AccessControl code is:

```
import Foundation
import LocalAuthentication

@objc open class AccessControl: NSObject {

  // Singleton
  @objc public static let shared = AccessControl()

  // Private
  private override init() {}

  // Policy
  private var policy: LAPolicy = .deviceOwnerAuthentication


  // Reason
  private var reason: String = "reason"


  @objc static func isAuthenticationSupported() -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let localAuthenticationContext = LAContext()
        if localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
            if #available(iOS 11.2, *) {
                return localAuthenticationContext.biometryType != .none
            } else {
                return localAuthenticationContext.biometryType != .LABiometryNone
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

@objc func evalute(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    var authError: NSError?
    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(policy, error:  &authError) else {
        completion(false)
        return
    }

    context.evaluatePolicy(policy, localizedReason: reason) { success, evaluateError in
        if success {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @objc func **evalute**(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void))

I assume the declaration should be

```
@objc func evaluate(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```